# Opening a combobox moves other controls

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp

[image]

I defined a RelativePanel that contains a combobox on the leftside and a toggleswitch right of the combobox. But for some reason, when click on the combobox to open it, a popup shows up with the contents and the combobox dissappears. (and becomes visible again by closing the popup). Because of that, the textblock containing the label for the combobox moves to the right and the popup overlaps my toggleswitch... 
How can i prevent this textblock from moving to prevent the popup from overlapping the toggleswitch? (it's the comboImageSources that is causing this problem, not the other combobox)

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="topBar" Grid.Row="0" Padding="12,0,12,0">

        <!-- left side -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="OCRSettings_Language"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                   Text="OCR Language:"
                   Margin="0,0,12,0"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" />

        <ComboBox x:Uid="comboSettingsOCRLanguage" x:Name="comboOCRLanguages"
                  AutomationProperties.Name="[comboSettingsOCRLanguage]"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Settings.OCRLanguages}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboOCRLanguageTemplate}"
                  RelativePanel.RightOf="OCRSettings_Language"
                  RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                  Margin="0,0,12,0"
                  TabIndex="8"
                  Loaded="comboOCRLanguages_Loaded" />

        <!-- right side -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="OCRSettings_ImageSource"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                   Text="Image Source:"
                   Margin="0,0,10,0"
                   RelativePanel.LeftOf="comboImageSources"
                   RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" />

        <ComboBox x:Uid="comboImageSources" x:Name="comboImageSources"
                  AutomationProperties.Name="[comboImageSources]"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Settings.ImageSources}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboImageSourceTemplate}"
                  RelativePanel.LeftOf="OCRSettings_ColumnMode"
                  RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                  Margin="0,0,20,0"
                  TabIndex="4"
                  Loaded="comboImageSources_Loaded"  />
```

Comment: Does it help or change anything if you remove the ItemTemplate-definitions from your comboboxes?

Comment: Nope. The itemtemplate defines what the combobox needs to show. In my case the name of the imagesource. If i delete it, the effect is just the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set the `Width` property to the `ComboBox` to some fixed value since it changes to really small value when you open the options in it.

Comment: I had to set a minWidth. I hate to do it tho. If a value in the box has a bigger width, i will probably have the same problem